# Querying the inner join of two tables with the same column name, Column 'exName' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, inner-join, ambiguous

I am querying the inner join of three tables using the following query.

Two of the tables  have columns named "name1". I am getting the following error.

```
Column 'exName' in field list is ambiguous
```

The "name1" columns are foreign key so the information should be identical. Can anyone suggest a compact way around this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name1,name2,name3 FROM `table1` INNER JOIN `table2` ON table2.name1=table1.PrimaryKey INNER JOIN `table3` ON table3.name1=table1.PrimaryKey");
```

Comment: alias the tables and specify which table you want your data to come from

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to qualify your column names with the table names.

```
 SELECT table1.name1, table2.name1, etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the columns in your select list as:

`SELECT <table name>.name1, <table name>.name2, <table name>.name3`

You can also give the tables an alias when you introduce them in the from clause to save some keystrokes and make things cleaner:

```
SELECT 
     t1.name1
    ,t2.name2
    ,t3.name3
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t2.name1 = t1.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t3.name1 = t1.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.name1,T2.name2,T3.name3 
FROM `table1` T1 
INNER JOIN `table2` T2 ON t2.name1=t1.PrimaryKey 
INNER JOIN `table3` T3 ON t3.name1=t1.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Its true you have to separate the columns by using the table name. for example,

```
 SELECT table1.name1, table2.name1, etc.
```

As @dud3 explained the issue of the column name `name1` from table1 `table1.name1` overwriting the one in table2 `table2.name1`.

You can use the `AS` statement when selecting them so that you receive them separately in the array. E.g

```
SELECT table1.name1, table2.name1 AS table2_name1, etc.
```

You can use any different column name to represent `table2_name1`. Here you will be with different column names in the formed array.